# What is the purpose of model files?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have seen many iOS projects that use model files JUST to list properties. As an example I have seen a customer's model file with the following properties:
first_name
last_name
account_number
etc.

Another example is an invoice model file with the following properties:
invoice_date
amount
notes
etc.

Is that the only thing that model files are used for?

Are there any resources that talk about best practice? Do you know?

Comment: Are you looking at just the .h files?  It can be done a couple ways, but I usually define my properties, vars, etc in the .h and the implementation in the .m file.  So you would have 2 per model, MyModel.h and MyModel.m that work together to construct the whole.  Also, a model may just be a simple class with properties that has no implementation or methods in the .m file

Comment: The latter is what I was referring to. I guess some classes are used to list properties and have nothing in the implementation file. Is there a name for this? Are they just called models?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650-207332-TPXREF151):

> A managed object model is a schema that provides a description of the
>   managed objects, or entities, used by your application.

Something as simple as your example may a bit too simple for Core Data, but add relationships and model versions, it very useful in managing an application's data model. From the model editor, you can generate the source files needed, store templates for fetch requests, and few other things.

There is a whole document dedicated to [model editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/about_cd_modeling_tool.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010379-CH3-SW1), which has a lot more information than can be fit in an answer here.